Invertible objects in tensor categories (with P. Deligne/J.S. Milne's definition)
$\newcommand\id{\mathrm{id}}$I've asked this question on MSE, but the only response I've gotten so far is a comment, which I failed to understand. I'll add another question I have, related to this.
Question 1: In Deligne and Milne - Tannakian categories, page 7 under the chapter on "Invertible objects" we call an object $L$ in a tensor category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ (I will abbreviate this to $\mathcal{C}$) invertible if there is an equivalence of categories $X \leadsto L \otimes X$.
It is said that if there exists an object $L'$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $L \otimes L' \cong \mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the (unique up to isomorphism) unit object, then $L$ is invertible.
I tried showing this myself. I believe I can show that the functors $(L \otimes -)$ and $(- \otimes L')$ acts as (quasi)-inverses on arbitrary objects $X \in \mathcal{C}$. For example, we have
$$(L \otimes -) \circ (- \otimes L')(X) = L \otimes (X \otimes L') \xrightarrow{\id_{L} \otimes \psi_{X,L'}} L \otimes (L' \otimes X) \xrightarrow{\phi_{L,L',X}} (L \otimes L') \otimes X \xrightarrow{\delta \otimes \id_{X}} \mathbf{1} \otimes X \xrightarrow{l_{X}^{-1}} X$$ which is a composition of isomorphisms, hence an isomorphism. Without having written it out in full, showing that $(- \otimes L') \circ (L \otimes -)$ acts as the identity should involve basically the same isomorphisms.
However, I don't immediately see how to show that $(L \otimes -)$ and $(- \otimes L')$ composed, acts (up to isomorphism) as the identity on arbitrary morphisms $f:X \to Y$. I'd appreciate any hint/explanation.
To clarify, I want to show that if $L \otimes L' \cong \mathbf{1}$ for some object $L'$ in $\mathcal{C}$, then $X \leadsto L \otimes X$ defines an equivalence of categories.
Since functors that are faithful, full and essentially surjective defines an equivalence of categories, we could instead perhaps go by this route.
Since $L \otimes X \otimes L' \cong X$ for arbitrary $X$, we see that $X \leadsto L \otimes X$ is essentially surjective.
If $\id_L \otimes f = \id_L \otimes g$, then it is not immediately obvious that $f = g$. Without additional assumptions, I believe this clearly fails (thinking about the category $R\textbf{-Mod}$). Possibly one can use $L \otimes L' \cong \mathbf{1}$ here.
With regards to fullness, I am also not sure.
Question 2: On the same page, P. Deligne/J.S. Milne says that if we have an invertible object $L$ with inverses $(L_1,\delta_1)$,$(L_2,\delta_2)$, then there is a unique morphism $\alpha:L_1 \to L_2$ such that $$\delta_2 \circ (\id_{L} \otimes \alpha) = \delta_1$$.
We can construct an isomorphism explicitly as
\begin{multline*}
L_1 \cong L_1 \otimes \mathbf{1} \overset{\id_{L_1} \otimes \delta_2^{-1}}{\xrightarrow{\;\;}} L_1 \otimes (L \otimes L_2) \overset{\phi_{L_1,L,L_2}}{\xrightarrow{\;\;}} (L_1 \otimes L) \otimes L_2 \overset{\psi_{L_1,L} \otimes \id_{L_2}}{\xrightarrow{\;\;}} (L \otimes L_1) \otimes L_2 \\
\cong \mathbf{1} \otimes L_2 \cong L_2
\end{multline*}
but that is as far as I get, as of now.
I'd appreciate anything that sheds light on this.

TeX note: \overset{blah}{\xrightarrow{}} is a very unusual construction, since \xrightarrow is meant to take an argument; \xrightarrow{blah} is probably what you want. I have edited accordingly. (mathtools provides an \xmapsto function, but MathJax doesn't seem to support it ($\xmapsto{\text{label}}$), so in this context I know no better solution than \overset{blah}\mapsto that you already used.)

The maps you are defining are natural isomorphisms. (Because each step is a natural isomorphism, using the definition of a symmetric monoidal category). So you have constructed a natural isomorphism between the two composites and the identity functor.

@PhilTosteson $\delta$ is not a natural isomorphism though, P. Deligne/J.S. Milne use $\approx$ for isomorphism. But they don't say that $\delta$ is a functorial isomorphism.

Maybe that does not matter though, hm. Is it the case that $X \leadsto L \otimes X$ is a natural transformation?

@LSpice Oh, I did not know about \xmapsto, thanks!

Why don't you just try $L'\otimes-$?

@Ben123 There is no sense in which $\delta$ could be functorial!  But $\delta \otimes id_X$ is functorial in $X$.

@PhilTosteson I think I managed to convince myself of what you said, yes; thanks. Still unsure about question 2.
